# How to get the current smart contract size in KB using web3 tool

Tags: web3js, blockchain

Suppose I deployed a smart contract on the Ethereum blockchain...and later added some storage data to the contract. I want to know the current contract size in KB programmatically from my web3 backend possibly using web3 js and ethers js.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: you want to know the amount of storage used? the size of the contract and the amount of storage aren't really related so you can't pull that info in as one blob. If you know the storage layout you could calculate the storage in use, but if you have mappings you'd need to know all the keys as there'd be no way to enumerate them natively

Comment: The 24k storage limit does it only refers to the size of the contract or the amount of storage or both?

Comment: just the contract's bytecode size. you can get the bytecode with web3 or ethers using `getCode`, but you wouldn't have been able to deploy a contract if it busts the limit

Comment: Okay, so what is the limit of storage that can be used and how would I find out how much storage is already used?

Comment: For example how many `Match` is theoretically possible to store for this contract: https://github.com/Tahlil/solidity-stress-test/blob/master/contracts/Oracle.sol

Comment: the common analogy is that the contract's storage is a huge array of memory slots. Each slot being 32-bytes wide, and there are 2 ** 256 slots available, which is huge. You don't need to worry about running out of storage, but gas costs would be a consideration